# Product of predictable process and a characteristic function is integrable

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Suppose the time parameter $t\in[0,T]$, $S$ is a Semimartingale and  $\theta_t$ a predictable $S$-integrable process such that

$$\int_0^T\theta_u dS_u\ge -a$$

for a $a>0$. Furthermore $\mathcal{F}_t$ denotes a filtration satisfying the usual conditions. Now let $A\in\mathcal{F}_t$. Why do we have

$$\int_0^T\theta_u \mathbf1_AdS_u\ge -a\tag{1}$$ 
i.e. the integral is well defined and also bounded by $-a$ from below? That the integral is well-defined follows from:

$$E[\int_0^T\theta_u^2\mathbf1_Ad\langle S\rangle_u]\le E[\int_0^T\theta_u^2d\langle S\rangle_u]<\infty$$

But why is $(1)$ true? thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't $\int \theta_u 1_A dS_u = 1_A \int \theta_u dS_u $ ?  So inequality only depends on $a > 0$ ?

Comment: @mike stupid me! you could turn your comment into an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @math : Unless mistaken, the stochastic integral using the indicator function is well defined only after time $t$. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge Can you please explain why it should just be well defined after time $t$? Since we have $\int\theta_u1_AdS_u=1_A\int\theta_udS_u$ and the latter stochastic integral is always well defined. Of course the whole thing would not be adapted anymore.

Comment: @math : take $A=\{\omega s.t. \theta_t\in [1,2]\}$ it is in $\mathcal{F}_t$ but $1_A.\theta_s$ is a predictable process only after time $t$ otherwise would have to know the future which implies in turn that it is not an appropriate integrand. Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge But since the characteristic function is not part of the stochastic integral, why has it to be predictable? Sorry if I do not understand you properly.

Comment: @math : if you put it into the integral then it is part of it. Your notation is at best misleading, simply false otherwise. I strongly recommand you not to use it. Best regards.

Comment: @mike: How can I see this $\int \theta_u 1_A dS_u=1_A \int \theta_u dS_u$? Could you give me a reverence?